# Adding a custom theme as a resource

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a custom `theme.dll`. My program works fine loading the DLL externally. What I am trying to do is make the theme and the program as one file. I added it as project resource, however I don't know if it will work or how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved! I merge the `theme.dll` and the `Application.exe` using [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge).

1. Copy the `DLL` and the `Application.exe` into the `ILMerge` folder
2. Open `command prompt` in the current folder ( SHIFT + Right Click )
3. Type in this command

> C:\ilmerge> ilmerge Application.exe theme.dll /out:MergedApp.exe /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1"

*I know this answer is not how to add a custom theme as a resource, but this solves my problem to make the DLL and EXE as a single file.